# Python sorting multiple attributes

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting

I have a dictionary like the following. Key value pairs or username:name

```
d = {"user2":"Tom Cruise", "user1": "Tom Cruise"}
```

My problem is that i need to sort these by the Name, but if multiple users contain the same name like above, i then need to sort those by their username. I looked up the sorted function but i dont really understand the cmp parameter and the lambda. If someone could explain those and help me with this that would be great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cmp` is obsolescent. `lambda` just makes a function.

```
sorted(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1, 0))
```

Comment: the thing is this is part of an assignment for my class and im not allowed to import libraries like operator. Its only builtin funcitons. I understand what you are getting at and i tried to improvise. I used "sorted(l, key=lambda l:(l[0], l[1]))", do you think this is equivalent to what you said?

Comment: Not quite. `lambda x: (x[1], x[0])`

Comment: so this function is sorting the names but if the names are the same then it sorts the username, or does it keep them the same position? Because i need it so that if the names are the same then it sorts by username. Thanks alot!

Comment: It sorts them by the key. The key is a tuple, and tuples sort element-wise. Element 0 is compared, but if they're the same then element 1 is compared, and so on.

Comment: so lets say you have tuples in a list [(3,2), (1,2), (1,1)] and you want to sort them by the second values in each, if the second values are the same then sort by the first. The answer i should expect is this [(1,1), (1,2), (3,2)]. Is this what the code is doing?

Comment: That is exactly correct, since it constructs new tuples arranged that way to use as the key.

Comment: Nice. Im guessing it should be the same with strings also right? And sorry to bother you again about this but lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), in the example with the tuples can you actually do like one iteration and tell me what would be stored in x when sorted() is ran? Like what is being compared at that instant or which tuples/ items in a tuple are compared? Just incase my prof asks me to explain what i did there :) thanks

Comment: Nothing is actually ever stored in `x`, it's just used as an argument for the lambda. A simplified way to look at it is that Python generates a sequence of the keys, sorts that, then rearranges the original sequence. So it generates `(2, 3), (2, 1), (1, 1)` and goes from there.

Comment: OHHH i see so it actually compares 2 tuples at a time and if they have the same values then it checks the others and sorts by that one. Like in the case where the first 2 tuples in the original list had '2' as the second value, so it sorted those by '1' and '3'?

Answer (score 5):

I'm just going to elaborate on Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer. `cmp` is deprecated. Don't use it. Use the `key` attribute instead.

`lambda` makes a function. It's an expression and so can go places that a normal `def` statement can't but it's body is limited to a single expression.

```
my_func = lambda x: x + 1
```

This defines a function that takes a single argument, `x` and returns `x + 1`. `lambda x, y=1: x + y` defines a function that takes an `x` argument, an optional `y` argument with a default value of 1 and returns `x + y`. As you can see, it's really just like a `def` statement except that it's an expression and limited to a single expression for the body.

The purpose of the `key` attribute is that `sorted` will call it for each element of the sequence to be sorted and use the value that it returns for comparison.

```
list_ = ['a', 'b', 'c']
sorted(list_, key=lambda x: 1)
```

Just read the rest for a hypothetical example. I didn't look at problem closely enough before writing this. It will still be educational though so I'll leave it up.
<strike>We can't really say much more because</strike>

1. You can't sort `dict`s. Do you have a list of `dicts`s? We could sort that.
2. You haven't shown a `username` key.

I'll assume that it's something like

```
users = [{'name': 'Tom Cruise', 'username': user234234234, 'reputation': 1},
         {'name': 'Aaron Sterling', 'username': 'aaronasterling', 'reputation': 11725}]
```

If you wanted to confirm that I'm more awesome than Tom Cruise, you could do:

```
sorted(users, key=lambda x: x['reputation'])
```

This just passes a function that returns the `'reputation'` value for each dictionary in the list. But `lambdas` can be slower. Most of the time `operator.itemgetter` is what you want.

`operator.itemgetter` takes a series of keys and returns a function that takes an object and returns a tuple of the value of its argument.

so `f = operator.itemgetter('name', 'username')` will return essentially the same function as
`lambda d: (d['name'], d['username'])` The difference is that it should, in principle run much faster and you don't have to look at ugly `lambda` expressions.

So to sort a list of `dict`s by name and then username, just do

```
sorted(list_of_dicts, operator.itemgetter('name', 'username'))
```

<strike>which is exactly what Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams suggested.</strike>

Comment: It looked to me like the key is the username, and the value is the real name.

Comment: @Ignacio - right. I somehow missed the `iteritems` in your solution.

Comment: OP specifies the dict as "Key value pairs or username:name" though that may have been edited in. I missed it at first.

Comment: @Josh Smeaton, right. I missed it. I think the `or` threw me off. I'm going to leave it up though because it provides a more in depth explanation of `lambda`, `itemgetter` and `key` than Ignacio's answer.

Comment: Definitely, I've only recently learnt about itemgetter and didn't know it could do key lookups as well as positional. +1

Comment: so is lambda is a function that iterates over and sets a value to the x eg. lambda x: x + 1? If lambda functions like that then the "key" parameter is the item to sort then right? The part i am confused about now is if you have 2 keys that are the same, what happens then? Thanks bro, really good explanation :)

Comment: @1337holiday: Python's sorting is stable, so two elements that have the same key keep their relative position in the sequence.

Comment: @1337holiday. `lambda` is just a function. In this case, `sorted` calls its `key` function once for every element of the list. The `lambda` function does exactly what you tell it to do. If you just tell it to get an attribute or key and return the value of a single item, then that's exactly what it does. So the `lambda` doesn't iterate at all.

Comment: I found the last line, `sorted(list_of_dicts, operator.itemgetter('name', 'username'))` doesn't work as it appears the second parameter to `sorted()` is meant to be a cmp function. Adding `key=` to identify the parameter as in `sorted(list_of_dicts, key=operator.itemgetter('name', 'username'))` works perfectly though.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that dict can't be sorted. But python 2.7 & 3.1 have this class collections.OrderedDict.

So,

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict({'D':'X','B':'Z','C':'X','A':'Y'})
>>> d
OrderedDict([('A', 'Y'), ('C', 'X'), ('B', 'Z'), ('D', 'X')])
>>> OrderedDict(sorted((d.items()), key=lambda t:(t[1],t[0])))
OrderedDict([('C', 'X'), ('D', 'X'), ('A', 'Y'), ('B', 'Z')])
```

Comment: yea actually it doesnt matter if its a dict, all i need is that if i have say people's names and usernames i need to sort the names but the problem arises if two or more people have the same name, in that case i need to sort those people by username (only those people).